How to extract vertex group information in FBXSDK C++?
I've already loaded the model, and I have access to the animation keyframes and keyvalues for each bone, however, my mesh has bones and each bone corresponds to a vertex group with specific control points, I need to extract those vertices that corresponds to those bones so I can animate them.
I tried to cast a bone node to a mesh node like so :
FbxMesh* bone_mesh = FbxCast<FbxMesh>(bone_node->GetNodeAttribute());

but it gives me a nullptr.

Is this what you're looking for?  Extract vertex data from an FBX file?

@DrewDormann no, in that link they're extracting the vertex data from one single mesh that has no bones, but when the mesh has different sections that corresponds to bones, you cannot extract it like that.
